# Running Node as a Service with Forever

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

The last time I deployed a nodejs application I used `forever` to run it as a service.

I have installed node6.0.0pre on a Ubuntu server 14.04 and when I run node ./bin/www I can test my application and it works ok.

**I run `forever`

```
forever start app.js 
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not        stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js**
```

However the application does not seem to work ... ideas ?

Comment: forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 app.js

Comment: actually the way recent node is configured by default you have to run ./bin/www instead of app.js

Comment: @avrono you are talking about express, not nodejs

Comment: @yellowsir, correct sorry for confusion